# Заполнение кастомного listview

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, есть кастомный listview состоящий из textview сверху, и нескольких imageview снизу, можно ли так сделать, чтобы каждый элемент списка ну, то есть 1-ый элемент содержащий textview и imageview заполняется теми данными которые я задаю, 2-ой уже другими. Если можно, то как это примерно сделать.
[image: Вот так они расположены]

**код xml-file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/na1"
            android:layout_width="383dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="просто текст"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/na2"
                android:text="просто текст 2"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <!-- android:src="@drawable/__1" />-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <!--  android:src="@drawable/__1b" />-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**код java-file**

```
package com.example.admin.orshagoes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class number_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] arr; //={"Вокзал", "Школа №12"};
    ListView listView1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_1);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        //arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1);

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> date = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(arr.length);

        Map <String, Object> map;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       map.put("name",arr[i]);
        date.add(map);
       }
        String [] from = {"name"};
       int [] to = {R.id.na1};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,date,R.layout.test2,from,to);

        // Создаём адаптер ArrayAdapter, чтобы привязать массив к ListView
       // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);

        // Привяжем массив через адаптер к ListView
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                finish();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс который сохраняет данные для каждой модели, в моем случае это класс DannieCoklanovza. Можете передавать строки. И да я использую вторую библиотеку которую скидывал

```
public
    class ContentModel_Clan_Sostav implements ItemModel
    {
        public static final int TYPE = 1;

        DannieCoklanovza dannieCoklanovza; //Тут могут быть любые данные





        public ContentModel_Clan_Sostav(@NonNull DannieCoklanovza dannieCoklanovza) {
            this.dannieCoklanovza = dannieCoklanovza;


        }

        @Override
        public
    int getType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    public DannieCoklanovza getDannieCoklanovza() {
        return dannieCoklanovza;
    }
}
```

ViwHolder, здесь мы иницилизируем наши TextView, могут быть и кнопки и другие элементы

```
  public
class ContentViewHolder_Clan_Sostav
        extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public final TextView name_textView;
    public final TextView dolznost_textView;
    public final TextView vremya_textView;

    public ContentViewHolder_Clan_Sostav(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name_textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_textView);
        dolznost_textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dolznost_textView);
        vremya_textView = (TextView);

    }
}
```

Здесь мы присваиваем данные

```
    public
class ContentViewRenderer_Clan_Sostav
        extends ViewRenderer<ContentModel_Clan_Sostav, ContentViewHolder_Clan_Sostav>
{
    @NonNull
    Context context;
    FragmentActivity activity;
    public ContentViewRenderer_Clan_Sostav(final int type, final Context context, final FragmentActivity activity, @NonNull final Listener listener) {
        super(type, context);
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public ContentViewRenderer_Clan_Sostav(int type, Context context, Listener mListener) {
        super(type, context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ContentViewRenderer_Clan_Sostav(int type, Context context) {
        super(type, context);
    }

    @Override
    public
    void bindView(@NonNull final ContentModel_Clan_Sostav model, @NonNull final ContentViewHolder_Clan_Sostav holder) {

         holder.name_textView.setText(model.getDannieCoklanovza().getMembers().getAccount_name());
         holder.dolznost_textView.setText(model.getDannieCoklanovza().getMembers().getRole_i18n());
         holder.vremya_textView.setText(model.getDannieCoklanovza().getPersonaly_dannie().getLogout_at());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContentViewHolder_Clan_Sostav createViewHolder(@Nullable final ViewGroup parent) {
        return new ContentViewHolder_Clan_Sostav(inflate(R.layout.items_content_clan_sostav, parent));
    }

    public
    interface Listener
            extends CategoryViewRenderer_Clan.Listener
    {
        void onContentItemClicked(@NonNull ContentModel_Clan_Sostav model);
    }
}
```

а теперь где я использую это

```
public class Fragment_clan_sostav extends Fragment {
LocationTanki locationTanki;
ArrayList<DannieCoklanovza> dannieCoklanovza;

private RendererRecyclerViewAdapter mRecyclerViewAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public static final int MAX_SPAN_COUNT = 1;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clan_sostav, container, false);

    locationTanki  = (LocationTanki) getActivity().getApplication();
    dannieCoklanovza = locationTanki.getDannieCoklanovzas();
    mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RendererRecyclerViewAdapter();
    mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerRenderer(new ContentViewRenderer_Clan_Sostav(ContentModel_Clan_Sostav.TYPE, getContext()));

    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), MAX_SPAN_COUNT);
    mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup()
    {
        @Override
        public
        int getSpanSize(final int position) {
            switch (mRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                case ContentModel_Clan_Sostav.TYPE:
                    return 1;
                default:
                    return 2;
            }
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.resurs);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new EqualSpacesItemDecoration(20));

    mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(getItems());
    mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    return view;
}

//Добавляем в список
@NonNull
private ArrayList<ItemModel> getItems() {
    final ArrayList<ItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < dannieCoklanovza.size(); i++)
    {
        items.add(new ContentModel_Clan_Sostav(dannieCoklanovza.get(i)));
    }

    return items;
    }

    public static Fragment_clan_sostav newInstance() {
        return new Fragment_clan_sostav();
    }
}
```

А так же лаяуты. Первый для фрагмента

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/perevod"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/resurs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

а так же `items_content_clan_sostav.xml` для моделей наших

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name_textView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dolznost_textView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vremya_textView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/perevod"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

И вот результат[image: Результат]

Answer (score 3):

Я бы вам посоветовал бы использовать RecyclerView,был создан в качестве улучшения ListView. Он является более гибким управлением для обработки «списками данных», которые следует модели делегирования проблем и оставляет за собой только одну задачу - переработка предметов.

Вот есть 2 библиотеки, там у них и есть примеры.

[RecyclerView со списками](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/README.md)

[RecyclerView 2](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)

Если вас заинтересует, могу выложить несколько примеров использования. Я в начале тоже думал использовать кастомный ListView, ну слишком много геморроя. RecyclerView намного упрощает заполнения данных, вид для данных, а так же создание событий для каждого элемента.

Comment: Ну если не трудно выложите пожалуйста.

Comment: это что гугл-транслейт? вы не русский?